# Single store to Cassandra migration

Tags: cassandra, singlestore

We are in the process of migrating Singlestore DB to Cassandra database .  As an initial setup, data modeling needs to be done.  We are planning to use data-xtractor for this modeling/migration activity.  Please let us know if this is a feasible approach to perform this activity.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used data-xtractor, but seems feasible reading over the process here:
https://data-xtractor.com/blog/apache-cassandra/relational-database-to-cassandra/

I'd just be sure you or perhaps a consultant with Cassandra knowledge reviews the data model once moved over.  In Cassandra you'll want to ensure the tables are defined to match your query needs, which can take more than a single iteration to get correct.  It will be too detailed to go over in a single SO post, but if you have any specific questions as you work through this, don't hesitate to reach out.